# OCaml Data structure to find count last elements

Tags: data-structures, ocaml

I'm looking for data structure which answer to following question ?
How many elements in lists is lower than current. And I would like to count it for every element in list. Additionally, it must be consistent subsequence of list.

For example:

```
[1;2;3;-3;5;3]
```

The correct answer is:

```
[0; 1; 2; 0; 4; 0]
```

Comment: The problem is not described clearly.  I would have conjecture that the solution to the above was [1;2;3;0;5;3] from the description above. Please try again to describe the desired algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm exactly understanding your question right because your 'correct answer' seems inconsistent with how you described the problem, but here is a possible solution to the described problem:

```
let xs = [1;2;3;-3;5;3] in 
let comp x y = 
    if (x < y) then -1
    else if (x > y) then 1
    else 0
in
let sorted_xs = List.sort comp xs in
let index x =
    let rec helper i xs =
        match xs with
        | [] -> failwith "Item not in list"
        | hd::tl -> (
            if (hd = x) then i
            else helper (i+1) tl
        )
    in helper 0 sorted_xs
in
List.map index xs
```

I'm not sure whether that is exactly the problem that you're trying to solve, but that should at least give you the general idea.

The result of this is [1;2;3;0;5;3] which is the number of other items in the list that are lower than the item at that index.

********UPDATE**************

This is the correct code based on what you described in the comments.  Let me know if this makes sense.

```
let xs = [1;2;3;-5;6;7;10;-1;4] in
let transfer_item xs1 xs2 =
   match xs1 with
   | [] -> failwith "Invalid list"
   | hd::tl -> (tl,hd::xs2)
in
let find_item xs i =
    let rec helper xs count =
        match xs with
        | [] -> count
        | hd::tl -> (
          if (hd > i) then count
          else helper tl (count+1)
        )
     in helper xs 0
in
let rec new_list xs ref_list =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> (
      let first = find_item ref_list hd in
      let (xs, ref_list) = transfer_item xs ref_list in
      first::(new_list xs ref_list)
    )
in new_list xs []
```

Comment: No, we can't sort elements. Order is important. 
I add one more example:
[1;2;3-5;6;7;10;-1;4] ---> [0;1;2;0;1;2;3;0;1]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you are getting that answer?  Clearly 10 is greater than every other element in the array so its value should be greater than 3, should it not?  Even if you're considering it in order, the number of values lower than 10 should then be 6, not 3.

Comment: yes, in hurry I made a mistake, I correct it:
[1;2;3;-5;6;7;10;-1;4] ---->  [0;1;2;0;4;5;6;0;1]

Comment: That still doesn't seem consistent to me because if I understand correctly then the output should be [0;1;2;0;4;5;6;1;5] or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: No, Now is OK. Why at the end can't be 5 as you suggest ?
Look, firstly previous lower number than 4 is -1, but previous previous - it is 10 > 4, so I can go back one poistion that 4 is still max. 

As for -1. Previous number is 10, so I can't go back, -1 isn't still max. Only possibility is 0, when I go back 0, -1 is still maximum

Comment: Ok so basically what you're saying is that you want the length of the longest preceding subset of numbers that is less than the current number.

Answer (score 0):

You can easlily solve your problem using two recursive functions: one for iterating in the list, and one for checking the predecessors in the list. The following code is a possible implementation:

```
let rec countElementsLessThan list value =

    match list with

        | []           -> 0

        | head :: tail -> if head < value
                          then 1 + (countElementsLessThan tail value)
                          else countElementsLessThan tail value

;;

(*******************************)

let rec count remaining alreadySeen result =

    match remaining with

        | []           -> result

        | head :: tail -> let elementsLessThanHead = countElementsLessThan alreadySeen head in
                          count tail (head :: alreadySeen) (result @ [elementsLessThanHead])

;;

(*******************************)

let rec printList list =

    match list with

        | []           -> print_newline ()

        | head :: tail -> print_int head;
                          printList tail

;;

(*******************************)

let result = count [1;2;3;-3;5;3] [] [];;
printList result;;
```

Here, method `count` will iterate and store the already seen elements in a list called `alreadySeen`. Then, for every element being checked, we call an auxiliary method `countElementsLessThan` that will return the number of elements lower than the current element. Finally, we store the result in the `result` list, until every element of the `remaining` list is checked.

However, I'm not completely sure of having perfectly understood your question, since for me the example you provided should have been:

> [1;2;3;-3;5;3] The correct answer is: [0; 1; 2; 0; 4; **3**]

instead of:

> [1;2;3;-3;5;3] The correct answer is: [0; 1; 2; 0; 4; 0]